# Rails form mix checkboxes and radio buttons on same parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my form I have `:option_ids` which passes a list of IDs back to the model to build associations with the applicable Options.  In my case there are groups of options allowing the user to select any combination of options.

Currently I have this in my form:

```
 - @option_groups.each do |group|
  - unless group.options.blank?
    .form
      h3 = group.name
      .checkboxes
        = line_item.collection_check_boxes :option_ids, group.options, :id, :name_and_price do |option|
          .checkbox.horizontal
            = option.check_box(class: "check")
            = image_tag option.object.photo.variant(resize: "65x65") if option.object.photo.attached?
            = option.label
```

Recently we added a condition to the OptionGroup model allowing users to define whether multiple options from this OptionGroup could be selected(checkboxes), or only one(radio buttons).

What I'm wondering is if there's a way I can still populate the :option_ids parameter using a combination of checkboxes and radio buttons.  I've tried the following but it messes up the params hash

```
 -@option_groups.each do |group|
  - unless group.options.blank?
    .form
      h3 = group.name

      - if group.multiple?
        .checkboxes
          = line_item.collection_check_boxes :option_ids, group.options, :id, :name_and_price do |option|
            .checkbox.horizontal
              = option.check_box
              = image_tag option.object.photo.variant(resize: "65x65") if option.object.photo.attached?
              = option.label

      - else
        span Please select one
        .checkboxes
          = line_item.collection_radio_buttons :option_ids, group.options, :id, :name_and_price do |option|
            .checkbox.horizontal
              = option.radio_button
              = image_tag option.object.photo.variant(resize: "65x65") if option.object.photo.attached?
              = option.label
```

Has anyone encountered a scenario like this before? How would someone conditionally impose exclusivity while not messing up the other id's in the form attribute?

Comment: Framework challenge: It doesn't make sense in the first place to use `option_ids` if there can only be one value. Apart from that you should probably be using `fields_for` to scope the inputs - but that really has nothing to do with your checkbox vs radio situation.

Comment: yeah I went ahead and switched to only using `collection_check_boxes` and using JS to selectively enforce exclusivity.  Im leaving this up for now because someone may have a good solution which will be valuable to the community.